# dropzone send all files at once in an array instead of one by one

Tags: dropzone

I have a problem with `dropzone` using `php` as backend.

The upload itself works (either one or multiple files) but the problem is that callbacks do not work, which might be because there is a new request for each file.

How do I send all the files at once as an array?

This is my dropzone js:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            acceptedFiles: "image/*",
            maxFilesize: 10,
            init: function () {
                this.on('completemultiple', function () {
                    console.log('done');
                    location.reload();
                });
            }
        }
```

And the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('uploadSponsors') }}" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span>Click or drag and drop images here</span></div>
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the php code I am using to check the number of files:

```
$images = $request->file('file');

$count = count($images);
```

So `$count` is always 1, even if I drop 3 images at once `$count` is always 1 . How can I make it so that `$count` is 3 if I drop 3 images and I have them in an array?

Answer (score 0):

i found some solution for your problem. add `parallelUploads` parameter in Dropzone Configuration.

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
   autoProcessQueue: false,
   uploadMultiple: true,
   parallelUploads:3,
   maxFiles :3,
   acceptedFiles: "image/*",
   maxFilesize: 10,
   init: function () {
       this.on('completemultiple', function () {
           console.log('done');
           location.reload();
       });
  }
}
```